# Why `ggplot2` returns a blank plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe in `R`

```
prop_data_tot<-structure(list(year_period = c("Q1 2011", "Q2 2011", "Q3 2011", 
                                              "Q1 2012", "Q2 2012", "Q3 2012", "Q1 2013", "Q2 2013", "Q3 2013", 
                                              "Q1 2014", "Q2 2014", "Q3 2014", "Q1 2015", "Q2 2015", "Q3 2015", 
                                              "Q1 2016", "Q2 2016", "Q3 2016", "Q1 2017", "Q2 2017", "Q3 2017", 
                                              "Q1 2018", "Q2 2018", "Q3 2018", "Q1 2019", "Q2 2019", "Q3 2019", 
                                              "Q1 2020", "Q2 2020", "Q3 2020", "Q1 2021", "Q2 2021", "Q3 2021", 
                                              "Q1 2022", "Q2 2022", "Q3 2022"), `Count false` = c(5L, 2L, 8L, 
                                                                                                  5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 32L, 11L, 21L, 33L, 67L, 90L, 86L, 
                                                                                                  175L, 1088L, 1505L, 1159L, 890L, 1309L, 810L, 1149L, 1338L, 2391L, 
                                                                                                  4504L, 2520L, 2335L, 1832L, 1530L, 1383L, 1073L, 608L, 220L), 
                              false = c(0.833333333333333, 1, 0.888888888888889, 
                                                          0.625, 0.272727272727273, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 0.6875, 
                                                          1, 0.545454545454545, 0.376470588235294, 0.916666666666667, 
                                                          0.7, 0.891891891891892, 0.656862745098039, 0.882352941176471, 
                                                          0.843137254901961, 0.870646766169154, 0.927536231884058, 
                                                          0.921616656460502, 0.845368344274252, 0.567602040816326, 
                                                          0.606299212598425, 0.512658227848101, 0.57536304456685, 0.641726618705036, 
                                                          0.742316050915865, 0.754944686557157, 0.852215082854244, 
                                                          0.9343737494998, 0.960167714884696, 0.964083175803403, 0.982942430703625, 
                                                          0.955476402493321, 0.971246006389776, 0.932203389830508), 
                              `Count true` = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 
                                               53L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 35L, 12L, 16L, 26L, 85L, 128L, 212L, 678L, 
                                               850L, 770L, 848L, 747L, 830L, 1462L, 437L, 164L, 76L, 57L, 
                                               24L, 50L, 18L, 16L), true = c(0.166666666666667, 
                                                                                               0, 0.111111111111111, 0.375, 0.727272727272727, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
                                                                                               0.3125, 0, 0.454545454545455, 0.623529411764706, 0.0833333333333333, 
                                                                                               0.3, 0.108108108108108, 0.343137254901961, 0.117647058823529, 
                                                                                               0.156862745098039, 0.129353233830846, 0.072463768115942, 
                                                                                               0.0783833435394979, 0.154631655725748, 0.432397959183673, 
                                                                                               0.393700787401575, 0.487341772151899, 0.42463695543315, 0.358273381294964, 
                                                                                               0.257683949084135, 0.245055313442843, 0.147784917145756, 
                                                                                               0.0656262505002001, 0.039832285115304, 0.0359168241965974, 
                                                                                               0.0170575692963753, 0.0445235975066785, 0.0287539936102236, 
                                                                                               0.0677966101694915)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")






library(ggplot2)
ggplot(prop_data_tot, aes(x = year_period)) +
         geom_line(aes(y = false, color = "False"), size = 0.8) +
         geom_line(aes(y = true, color = "True"), size = 0.8) +
         labs(x = "Year Period", y = "Fact Checked") +
         scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
         theme_minimal()
```

With the `ggplot2` code I would like to obtain in the same plot the graph of columns `false` and `true` by time (`Q1 2011` refer to the first trimester of 2011, `Q2 2011` to the second trimester of 2011 and so on), i.e. I would like to create a line plot with two lines representing `false` and `true` by time. But the result that instead I obtained is the following:

[image]

Why? How I could fix this issue? moreover, would it be possible to make the arrangement of the labels on the horizontal axis of the graph less dense?

Comment: Side note to the answers you've already had - it's generally a poor idea to use protected words like 'true' and 'false' as variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively please check the below code where I reshaped the data to `long format` and use group option

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- prop_data_tot %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(false,true), names_to = 'name', values_to = 'value') %>% 
  mutate(order=as.numeric(gsub('\\w\\d\\s','',year_period)))


ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(year_period, order), y=value, group=name)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=name)) +
  labs(x = "Year Period", y = "Fact Checked") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1)) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend("Name"))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The problem with your code is that it doesn't draw the curves in the correct time order. As you can see from your chart Q1 2012 comes before Q2 2011 which is not true because Q1 2012 is Q1 2012 while Q2 2011 is Q2 2011